# Fatalfallbackerrorhandler getting called though handled is set to true

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, spring-camel

I have a camel route as that of below. Though I set handled(true), I am not getting why defaulterrorhandler is calling fatalfallbackerrorhandler after all retries got exhausted.

```
onException(Exception.class)
    .handled(true)
    .to("direct:errors")          ----->  (1)
    ;                    

from("direct:errors")
    .log("hello world ");

from("timer:testRoute")
   .routeId("testRoute_1")
   .throwException(new Exception("Dummy Exception"))
   .pollEnrich("file://source")
   .to(http://localhost:8080)
```

Logs:

20.04.03 11:46:53.907  INFO ad #6 - timer://testRoute                            route1 BreadCrumbId=ID-xxxxxx-1585894556662-0-4 | hello world

20.04.03 11:46:53.913 ERROR ad #6 - timer://testRoute mel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler BreadCrumbId=ID-xxxxxx-1585894556662-0-4 | Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-xxxxxx-1585894556662-0-5 on ExchangeId: ID-xxxxxx-1585894556662-0-4). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 4 caught: java.lang.Exception: Dummy exception. Processed by failure processor: FatalFallbackErrorHandler[Channel[sendTo(direct://errors)]]

If, I comment the line (1) defaulterrorhandler is not calling fatalfallbackerrorhandler.

Answer (score 0):

This look perfectly valid. I even tried it in a test class and **it worked as you expect**, the timer "generates" a log entry every second.

In fact it is the message forward to `direct:errors` that is retried 5 times and does not succeed. This is strange because the `direct` component is part of camel-core.

I would suggest to check your project dependencies. Have you different Camel JARs with different versions on your classpath? If you use Maven, you can try the [Maven enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) to check for classpath conflicts.

Comment: Actually I am interested in why fatalfallbackerrorhanlder is getting called by defaulterrorhandler, as there is no exception generated by onException block.

Comment: Because an exception occurs in the exception handling block (not possible to send message to direct endpoint). The fatalfallbackerrorhanlder is the last resort to catch errors during error handling.

Comment: Actually exception is produced by timer:testRoute, which is being handled by onException block. I don't think that exchange is getting failed while sending to direct:errors from onException block. Because in logs hello world is getting printed.

Comment: According to the logs you posted, the exception occurs when sending to direct endpoint: `Processed by failure processor: FatalFallbackErrorHandler[Channel[sendTo(direct://errors)]]` therefore it is very obvious that the problem disappears when you comment out this line.

Comment: See also the JavaDoc of [FatalFallbackErrorHandler](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.19.1/org/apache/camel/processor/FatalFallbackErrorHandler.html). It is (as the name implies) the fallback error handler for errors during error handling.

Comment: I apologize for incomplete logs, I just updated the logs. If an exception occurs while sending to direct:errors route, hello world will never be printed in the logs. But, from the logs it clear that exception is not produced while sending to direct:errors. I think camel internally calling failure processor method.
Method: deliverToFailureProcessor, Ref: https://github.com/Talend/apache-camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/processor/RedeliveryErrorHandler.java#L1100

Comment: This is very strange, but as I wrote in my answer, there is probably a problem in your project setup. Your routes work perfectly for me and I get no errors.